# Join two tables by name for dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have a script that is reading my wheel brands. If I select a wheel it show all the wheels from that brand...

But because I did GROUP BY merk_naam so in my dropdown there wont be 100 same brands I cant show them all...

Can somebody help me with the following:

I have two tables now:

Table 1: it_merken

[Table 1](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/525/table1d.png/)

Table 2: it_merken2

[Table 2](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/24/table1r.jpg/)

I want the merk_naam in a dropdown list

But when I do that I get a lot of double ones like AS 2 time in this example...

I want to JOIN in table 1 and table 2 the merk_naam in one query...

I cant figure out how...

Can somebody help me out?

This is the class I got now with the GROUP BY:

```
<?php

class merken extends connect
{   
    /**
     * Merken lijst
     * 
     * @param object
     */
    private $merkenlijst;

    /**
     * Vraag merken op uit database
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return array
     */
    public function getMerken($database, $id = NULL)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT merk_code, merk_logo, merk_naam, wiel_foto, wiel_nummer, wiel_info FROM ".$database."_merken";
        if(!empty($id))
        {
            $sql .= " WHERE merk_code=:id"; 
        }
        else
        {
            $sql .= " GROUP BY merk_naam";
        }
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            if(!empty($id)){ $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_STR); }
            $stmt->execute();
            $this->merkenlijst = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $stmt->closeCursor();

            return $this->merkenlijst;
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            die ( $e->getMessage() );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Maak een database object en sla de data op
     *
     * @param object $dbo
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($dbo = NULL)
    {
        /*
         * Roep de parent constructor aan om te controleren op
         * een database object
         */
        parent::__construct($dbo);
    }
}

?>
```

That is given me each brand one time in my dropdown but when I select nothing, I want to show all brands and because I use GROUP BY now I only see one wheel per brand after submit.

This is my PHP and HTML:

```
<div class="bandwielkolom">
                        <form name="wielenzoeken" action="index.php?lang=<?php echo $lang; ?>&amp;p=<?php echo $_GET['p']; ?>#keuze" method="post">
                            <table class="wielentabel">
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="2"><?php echo $searchwheelsbybrand; ?><a name="wiel"></a></th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $brand; ?>:</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="wiel_merk" onchange="enable()">
                                            <option value="0">- <?php echo $brand; ?> -</option>
<?php
    $merken = $merkclass->getMerken($website, $merk);
    foreach($merken as $merk)
    {
        echo "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<option value=\"".$merk->merk_code."\"";
        if(isset($_GET['search']) && $_GET['search'] == "wiel" && isset($_GET['merk']) && $_GET['merk'] != "0" || isset($_POST['wiel_submit']) && $_POST['wiel_merk'] != "0") { echo " selected=\"selected\""; }
        echo ">".$merk->merk_naam."</option>\n";
    }
?>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td><input type="submit" name="wiel_submit" value="<?php echo $search; ?>"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearboth"></div>
                    <div id="main-right">             

<?php
foreach($teksten as $tekst)
{
    ?>
                    <h1><strong><?php echo $tekst->tekst_header; ?></strong></h1>
                    <?php echo $tekst->tekst_content."\n"; ?>
                    <?php
                        if(!empty($tekst->tekst_img))
    {
?>
                                                <div class="imgcontainer">
                        <div class="imgcontent">
                            <img src="<?php echo $tekst->tekst_img; ?>" class="content_image" alt="<?php echo $tekst->tekst_header; ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
<?php
    }
?>

<?php
}

?>
</div>
</div>
                    <div class="clearboth"></div>
                    <div id="main-left">
                    <ul class="wheels">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['wiel_submit']) && $_POST['wiel_submit'] == $search || isset($_GET['merk']))
{
    $merk = NULL;
    if(isset($_POST['wiel_submit']) && $_POST['wiel_submit'] == $search)
    {
            echo "\t\t\t\t\t<h2>".$brandselection."</h2>
\t\t\t\t\t<br />\n";
        $merk = $_POST['wiel_merk'];
    }
?>
<?php

    $merken = $merkclass->getMerken($website, $merk);
        foreach($merken as $merk)
    {
?>
                                            <li><span class="title"><?php echo $merk->wiel_info; ?></span>
                            <a href="http://www.website.nl/website/images/w3/<?php echo $merk->wiel_foto; ?>" class="preview" title="Fotonummer: <?php echo $merk->wiel_foto;  ?>">
                                <img src="http://www.website.nl/website/images/w3/<?php echo $merk->wiel_foto; ?>" alt="Fotonummer: <?php echo $merk->wiel_foto; ?>" class="wheelImg"/>
                            </a>
                            <span class="descr">
                            <img src="http://www.website.net/preview/bnet/logos/<?php echo str_replace(".png", "_100.png", $merk->merk_logo); ?>" style="padding-left:45px;" width="100" class="logo-merk" alt="<?php echo $merk->merk_naam; ?>"/>
                            </span>
                                </li>                         
<?php
    }
?>
</ul>
<?php
}
?>
        </div>
```

Any help is welcome because I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting doubles because some some of the fields in your SQL do not match, so you get a record for each.

Comment: From your code it seems like att you need it merk_code and merk_naam get rid of the other fields from the select and try again. $sql = "SELECT merk_code, merk_logo FROM ".$database."_merken";

Comment: No I just want the merk_naam in the my dropdown for each brand. When I remove my GROUP BY I get a long list with double brands. Thats why I use GROUP BY but when I dont select a brand and press submit I want to show all brands in my table... But because of the GROUP BY I only get one wheel at one brand and not more wheels by a brand... How can I make this right?